# Microsoft Excel Bitshift in formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Is it possible to bit-shift a number in a formula in Microsoft Excel?

I want to do something equivalent to

```
=(a1<<2)
```

I know I could just divide/multiply by a power of 2 and round, but this would be simpler.

UPDATE:
I am using Excel 2010 so I do not have access to BITLSHIFT.

Answer (score 1):

E2: `=BIN2DEC(RIGHT(TEXT(DEC2BIN(A2),0)&REPT("0",B2),C2))`
E3: `=RIGHT(MID(A3,3,LEN(A3))&REPT(0,B3),C3)`
F2: `=BIN2DEC(REPT("0",B2)&MID(DEC2BIN(A2,8),1,LEN(DEC2BIN(A2,8))-B2))`
F3: `=REPT(0,B3)&MID(A3,1,LEN(A3)-B3)`

[image]

Comment: That does not work.  If I put the number "16" in, I would expect to get 64 but get 61.

Comment: Oh you're right. I misunderstood and responded in a rush. I was expecting binary input and I did the operation incorrectly anyway. Two strikes. I've updated it.

Comment: I've updated the answer to give the general solution. You can choose right or left, number of places, and the output length.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the correct syntax but there is a BITLSHIFT and a BITRSHIFT function in Excel.

You can see more about it here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/BITRSHIFT-function-274D6996-F42C-4743-ABDB-4FF95351222C

Comment: See my addition to the question.  I am using 2010 so I do not have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

we can do the following simple math:

```
= BINRSHIFT(number, shift_value)
```

is equivalent to

```
= number/(2^shift_value)
```

Similarly,

```
=BINLSHIFT(number, shift_value)
```

is equivalent to

```
= number*(2^shift_value)
```